# conditional css for ie 10 and mozilla in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am using CSS for my ASP.net application. I am using the following code for proper alignment. It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but not working in IE 10. In my code I am using nested "div" but in IE my inner div text is going out of outer div.

```
<div id="divTermsConditions">
        <div class='Orangetitle'>
            <Mycontrols:MYLabel ID="lblTermsConditions" CssClass="TcHeader" runat="server" TextKey="TermsAndConditions"></Mycontrols:MYLabel>
        </div>
</div>
```

Rendered in the browser as:

```
<div id="divTermsConditions">
    <div class="Orangetitle">
        <span id="lblTermsConditions" class="TcHeader">Terms and conditions</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.TcHeader
{
    margin-left: -187px;
}
```

For IE10 below code is working file

```
.TcHeader
{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Option:

1. Is there any suitable CSS which will work in all browsers and resolve my issue?
2. Or, should I write separate CSS files for both IE and Mozilla? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: We need to see your rendered HTML, not your ASP.NET source.

Comment: Firstly, check the IE dev tools for the browser mode; confirm that you're not in Quirks mode. Secondly, the ASP source is useless for helping; we need to see the actual HTML in a form that can reproduce the bug. Preferably you would also create a jsFiddle example as well to show us the problem.

Comment: @Spudley - In IE10 browser Mode-IE10, and Document Mode: IE9 Standards and Second this is my HTML Code which is showing in DevTools <div id="divTermsConditions">
<div class="Orangetitle">
<span id="lblTermsConditions" class="TcHeader">Terms and conditions</span>
</div>

Comment: @santoshsahu - thanks. Just so you know, It's better to edit the question rather than posting the code as a comment; much easier to read. I've done that for you. Re the mode: I'd recommend being in IE10 standards mode rather than IE9 mode, but that shouldn't affect this question.

Comment: Are you able to produce a working example for us in http://jsFiddle.net? It will make it a lot easier to see what you mean. With the code we have, I can't see anything that would require separate styles, so I presume there's something else going on that's affecting it.

Comment: Are you really developing for [Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/)? Or do you mean Firefox?

Answer (score -1):

You should add `<html data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">`
and then add below code in css

```
.TcHeader [data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0']
{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Is this User-Agent detection? Is this adding the exactly same `data-*` value to all browsers? I'm yet to understand what it should do